# How to add a special Woocommerce "buy now" button?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I wish to ADD a "buy now" button on product page , and redirect to checkout page after clicking it **but without adding the product into cart.**

For example, if there are already products A,B in the cart , and I click the 'buy now' button on another product page of C , A and B in the cart will be still in the cart and remain not checkout, Only C will be in the product list of the checkout page and also C is not adding into cart.

I think this question can't simple be addressed by current wordpress and woocommerce code , I was thinking add another cart and checkout instances only for the "but now" checkout but I am not sure how to do it.

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to add the product to the cart them simply go into your content-single-product.php file and create an element that has an anchor tag that links directly to your cart wherever you want it to show up.

so it'd be something like:

```
<div class='cart-redirect'>
    <a src='http://yoursite.com/cart'>Checkout Now</a>
</div>
```

and just style it to look like a button.